# Limiting loop repetition in python

Tags: python, loops

I have a program that uses a loop, the thing is though, how can a make that loop repeat only a given amount of times? Code example below.

```
while True:
    print "This should be reprinted only ten times"
```

How can I make this code repeat itself only ten, or any given amount of times?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
for i in range(10):
    print "This should be reprinted only ten times"
```

OR

```
i=0
while i < 10:
    print "This should be reprinted only ten times"
    i+=1
```

OR SIMPLY

```
print "This should be reprinted only ten times\n"*10
```

For a range and random number:

```
from random import randint
num = randint(5,10)
print "This should be reprinted only {} times\n".format(num)*num
```

Comment: How could I make it so it reprints a random amount of times in a certain range?

Comment: @TheNotGoodAtCodeGuy, If my answer was helpful, would you mind accepting it? Thank you.